# Stopping time for adapted random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I am given a problem; if ${F_n}$ is a filtration wrt a sequence of random adapted variables ${Y_n}$, then if N is a stopping time, we have that $Y_N \in F_N$.

I believe that either this is a trivial one liner or I am missing some broader context. The setup should directly imply that $Y_n \in F_n$ for all $n\geq1$, in which case, since $N\geq1$, shouldn't it just follow immediately by the fact that ${Y_n}$ are random adapted variables?

Please let me know what I am missing here. It seems as simple as "this is true for all $n\geq1$, so is it true for $n=3$?" but this is silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be misunderstanding the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F_N$. When $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a filtration and $N$ is a random variable, then "$\mathcal F_N$" does $\textbf{not}$ mean that you "plug in" $N$ into $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

Instead, $\mathcal F_N$ is defined as $$\mathcal F_N = \{A\in\mathcal F: A\cap \{N\leq n\}\in \mathcal F_n, \forall n\}$$

Now you can approach the proof by noting that $$\{Y_N\in A\} = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \{Y_n\in A\}\cap \{N=n\}$$ and then you use the fact that the $Y_n$ are adapted and $N$ is a stopping time.